# Apply video effects

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-videoview, video-processing

I am creating an application, in which I have to give the option to apply different effects (normal, sepia, black & white, vintage, HD) to the VIDEO. I am creating this application for android version 2.3 . 
I am thinking of following the flow  video -> convert to image frames -> apply effect to frames using some library -> convert frames to video.

Can anyone help me that if above flow is correct or not? And which library I can use for applying effects to the frames or is there any other way to apply the effects to the video?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above flow is correct. The effects are applied to each frame separately. The library you are looking for is called [OpenCV](http://opencv.org).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I searched and found out that I can use ffmpeg for giving effects because OpenCV is used for high level effects like edge detection to the video.

Comment: @ishan jain:Can you give me some hint how did you give effects to video, can you give some example ffmpeg command, i can trim , rotate and concat video but not able to give effects, i am using colorchannelmixer but that command is not working for me